# How do I ask a question without inserting code on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, questions

Sometimes I need only suggestion and not the resolution of the issue with the code.

For instance, if I am thinking of making any tool and while doing analysis if I get confused about, how will I do that? or is my approach correct? or is there any better way to do that?

Before building any application I have to sit and think of what will I do and how will I do it. This is nothing but part analysis phase.

If I get stuck in the analysis phase then how should I ask the question on Stack Overflow (if the question is technical)?

Stack Overflow doesn't allow posting a question without inserting code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If I get stuck in the analysis phase then how should I ask the
>   question on Stack Overflow.

First of all: there is no guarantee that the question belongs on Stack Overflow so don't make it your mission to try and put it there. The type of question you are thinking to ask has a likelihood to become too broad, so do read the help center on asking questions before you go ahead and post a question.

That being said, if you have a very specific question that you can ask that does not boil down to "I don't know what to do, guide me", then in the analysis phase the "code" will likely boil down to diagrams.

As said there is no strict requirement to include code; that is simply a very easy example to use in the documentation because most programming problems will involve code in some way or another. But the true requirement is: make your question *answerable*, right from the get-go.

Questions that require people to basically drill you for more information are doomed to not survive the competition battle with the many other questions that roll in constantly, it will likely end up being put on hold. If you ask a question about code, add the relevant code. If you want to maximise the chance someone will be able to answer, make that code runnable so people can see with their own eyes what the problem is. Get an error? Include the error! It is really not all that mysterious, its just common sense. If you ask a question about *something*, that *something* must be physically present within the question itself.

So if you ask a question about application design, include the design or at least what you have so you yourself have a base to work on to explain what is missing or wrong.

---

Again: I'm not saying your question is going to be on-topic. That cannot be judged until you actually write a question. When you are not in the programming phase yet, maybe there is a better site to ask your questions on. [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for example.

Comment: for example in a question like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34174207/how-to-change-indentation-in-visual-studio-code
how can you expect the questioner to insert his codes while there is actually no code or there is no need to insert that?
i think this question is about this.

Answer (score 10):

There is no strict requirement to include code in a question, but you'll still have to keep your questions specific enough so it can be answered without the answer being opinion-based.